# My PHP Registration form wont work

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a registration form and passing in `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `salt` on my form. However for some reason my codes won't go on. Even if I will enter the right information on my form it won't just process it correctly. Basically I created a function that will do the verification.

Here's my codes:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("new-connection.php");

    global $connection;
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['last_name']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
        $salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));
        $encrypted_password = md5($password . '' . $salt);

if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == 'register'){
    //call to function
    register_user($_POST); //use the ACTUAL POST
}

elseif(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == 'login'){
        login_user($_POST);
}else{
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: homepage.php');
    die();
}

function register_user(){ //just a parameter called post
    $_SESSION['errors'] = array();

    if(empty($first_name)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "first name can't be blank!";
    }

    if(empty($last_name)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "last name can't be blank!";
    }

    if(empty($password)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "password is required!";
    }

    if($password != $post['confirm_password']){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "passwords must match!";
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "please use a valid email address!";

    }
    //end of validation 

    //now count errors
    if(count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0){
        header('Location: homepage.php');
        die();
    }else{      

        $query = "INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, password, email, created_at, updated_at)
                  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name','$password', '$email', NOW(), NOW())";

        $result = run_mysql_query($query); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "user successfully added";
        header('Location: homepage.php');
        die();
    }


}

function login_user($post){ //just a parameter called post
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.password = '{$post['password']}' 
    AND users.email = '{$post['email']}'";

    $user = fetch($query); //go and grab all users on above condition

    if(count($user) > 0){
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user[0]['id'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user[0]['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header('Location: success-homepage.php');
        die();
    }else{
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "cant find users";
        header('Location: homepage.php');
        die();
    }

}

?>
```

Any idea what went wrong???

NOTE: It wont insert the record + its giving the error on $_SESSION even the data entered is correct.

Comment: Where is `run_mysql_query` defined? It is not standard PHP.

Comment: register_user() function doesn't know what $first_name etc. are, unless you make them global, or pass them as parameters

Comment: You haven't posted the code that actually executes the query. There's no attempt here to check any errors in the MYSQL call so I assume that code is the same. Without proper error checking you have no way to know what's gone wrong.

Comment: Please read about SQL Injection and PDO

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard as the OP is clearly not using OOP why even considering using PDO a more sensable step would be to use mysqli OOP but `mysqli_*` is still better than `mysql_*` . Als he is escaping user input but he also ruins it by just passing the `$_POST` to a function

Comment: @RodelGarcia has any of the answers below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

What is it the error ? If you have a White page, insert in the top of the page:

```
error_reporting (E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("new-connection.php");

    global $connection;
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['last_name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));
    $encrypted_password = md5($password . '' . $salt);

if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == 'register'){
    //call to function
    register_user($firstname, $last_name, $email, $password, $salt, $encrypted_password); //use the ACTUAL POST // Cant only use post because isn't escaped
}

elseif(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == 'login'){
        login_user($email, $password);
}else{
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: homepage.php');
    die();
}

function register_user($firstname, $last_name, $email, $password, $salt, $encrypted_password){ // Pass all escaped variables here becasue the $_POST isn't escaped
    $_SESSION['errors'] = array();

    if(empty($first_name)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "first name can't be blank!";
    }

    if(empty($last_name)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "last name can't be blank!";
    }

    if(empty($password)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "password is required!";
    }

    if($password != $post['confirm_password']){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "passwords must match!";
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "please use a valid email address!";

    }
    //end of validation 

    //now count errors
    if(count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0){
        header('Location: homepage.php');
        die();
    }else{      

        // Add backticks around column and table names to prevent mysql reserved words error
        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
                  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name','$password', '$email', NOW(), NOW())";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "user successfully added";
        header('Location: homepage.php');
        die();
    }


}

function login_user($email, $password){ //just a parameter called post
    // No need to add table name
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password` = '$password' 
    AND `email` = '$email'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
         $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //go and grab all users on above condition
       // Check if there was atleast 1 user with the specified credentials
       if(count($user) >= 1){
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
          $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
          $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
          header('Location: success-homepage.php');
          die();
       }else{
          $_SESSION['errors'][] = "cant find users";
          header('Location: homepage.php');
          die();
       }
  } else {
    echo 'no user was found';
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe this works, maybe it doesn't. It's just a code dump with no attempt at any sort of explanation of what you have changed (if anything) or why.

Comment: Then you haven't red the comments yet